# Combine two arrays on key/value and output combined array with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Racking my brain on this, found many examples of similar situations however the solutions don't seem to match up.

I have two arrays being built as the result of SQL queries on different databases.

One is coming through formatted as such:

```
$data = array([$sku] => array(['LocalSKU'] => $sku,
                              ['Price'] => $msrp,
                              ['Price2'] => $wholesale,
                              ['Price3'] => $distributor,
                              ['Price4'] => $map))
```

The other array is formatted as such:

```
$matchme = array([0] => array(['entity_id'] => $entity_id,
                              ['sku'] => $sku,
                              ['type_id'] => $type_id))
```

Currently, I can get the individual data to match up via:

```
echo $matchme[0]['sku'];
echo $matchme[0]['entity_id'];
echo $matchme[0]['type_id'];
echo $data[$matchme[0]['sku']]['Price'];
echo $data[$matchme[0]['sku']]['Price2'];
echo $data[$matchme[0]['sku']]['Price3'];
echo $data[$matchme[0]['sku']]['Price4'];
```

However, when I try and merge the matching rows in both arrays, I get an empty array. The $data array contains 74 unique $sku, and $matchme is the result of checking those $sku's against a database and returning an array with 61 elements. So, the combined array should have 61 elements with matched pricing data based on the $sku.

How I am attempting to build the combined array is below, can anyone point me towards what I am doing wrong?

```
foreach($matchme as $key){
if(in_array($matchme[$key]['sku'], $data)){
    $matched_luggage[$matchme[$key]['sku']][] = array(
                                'sku' => $matchme[$key]['sku'],
                                'entity_id' => $matchme[$key]['entity_id'],
                                'type_id' => $matchme[$key]['type_id'],
                                'MSRP' => $data[$matchme[$key]['sku']]['Price'],
                                'Wholesale' => $data[$matchme[$key]['sku']]['Price2'],
                                'Distributor' => $data[$matchme[$key]['sku']]['Price3'],
                                'MAP' => $data[$matchme[$key]['sku']]['Price4']
                               );
}
}
```

In the above example, evaluate $key as 0, and the value of ['sku'] are matching.

------------------------Edited-------------------------

Per request, here is the result of print_r($data) truncated for space:

```
Array
(
[12PK-TITANIUM-CR123A] => Array
    (
        [LocalSKU] => 12PK-TITANIUM-CR123A
        [Price] => 11.76
        [Price2] => 10.32
        [Price3] => 0
        [Price4] => 0
    )

[AA-CLAMSHELL] => Array
    (
        [LocalSKU] => AA-CLAMSHELL
        [Price] => 0.25
        [Price2] => 0
        [Price3] => 0
        [Price4] => 0
    )

[AAA-CLAMSHELL] => Array
    (
        [LocalSKU] => AAA-CLAMSHELL
        [Price] => 0.25
        [Price2] => 0
        [Price3] => 0
        [Price4] => 0
    )

[AE-AEL280PI] => Array
    (
        [LocalSKU] => AE-AEL280PI
        [Price] => 0
        [Price2] => 0
        [Price3] => 0
        [Price4] => 0
    ) )
```

Per request, here is the result of print_r($matchme) truncated for space:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [entity_id] => 693
        [sku] => 12PK-TITANIUM-CR123A
        [type_id] => simple
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [entity_id] => 2596
        [sku] => AE-AEL480HL
        [type_id] => simple
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [entity_id] => 2597
        [sku] => AE-AEL600-T6
        [type_id] => simple
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [entity_id] => 2598
        [sku] => AE-AEWL2
        [type_id] => simple
    ) )
```

Per request, here is the desired result of $matched_luggage:

```
$matched_luggage = array( [12PK-TITANIUM-CR123A] => array([sku] => 12PK-TITANIUM-CR123A,
                                                          [entity_id] => 693,
                                                          [type_id] => simple,
                                                          [Price] => 11.76,
                                                          [Price2] => 10.32,
                                                          [Price3] => 0,
                                                          [Price4] => 0))
```

with an additional array per matched sku.

Comment: Sorry, I've read this 2 times but I'm not still not quite sure what you're trying to achieve. Can you post the `print_r()` output of the array and the expected output?

Comment: Added the requested information. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: It is not so readable right now. It'd help if you can wrap the statement in `<pre>` tags, like so: `echo '<pre>'.print_r($your_array_goes_here, true).'</pre>';`.

Comment: Updated to include pre tag wrapped arrays for easier reading, also truncated results to only 4 from each array to conserve space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach ($matchme as $arrProduct) {
    if (isset($data[$arrProduct['sku']])) {
        $arrMerged[$arrProduct['sku']]=array_merge($arrProduct, $data[$arrProduct['sku']]);
    }
}

print_r($arrMerged);
```

The reason your code doesn't work is here:

```
if(in_array($matchme[$key]['sku'], $data)) [...]
```

What `in_array()` does is tell you whether your *needle* (in your case the SKU string) exists as a value of array *haystack* (in your case, $data).  You are essentially trying to match a string to an array, rather than another string.

What you really want is just to match the SKU string to the key of $data, for which `isset()` is probably the simplest approach.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your first array as `$first` and second array as `$second`

```
foreach ($first as $key => $each) {
  foreach ($second as $secondeach) {
    if($secondeach['sku'] == $key) {
      $first[$key] = array_merge($first[$key], $secondeach);
      // unset since you do not want LocalSKU value anymore.
      unset($first[$key]['LocalSKU']);
    }
  }
}
```

`$first` is your array you wanted.